# Should I have one ViewModel class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for each Model class?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Basically, I have a model with various classes that load my data in different collections, including collections of collections (e.g. `Cart` has a collection of `Bundle`, which has collections of `Product`) . If my understanding of MVVM is correct, I would need to make one ViewModel class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged (directly or through inheritance from a base class) for each of my model classes. Though I must admit it seems to me that it implies a lot of duplicated code, just, having the ViewModel associate each property of the model class with a OnPropertyChanged call.
Just like is shown in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/) article for instance.
Am I getting this right ?

I'm currently trying to understand the basics of MVVM, so I try to fully implement it in my programs without any additional framework (MVVM Light and others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a ViewModel-Class for each Model-Class you have. Your Model-Classes should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`-Interface.

You need ViewModels to interact with your Views. In the ViewModels you can have instances of your Model-Classes.

Btw.: To avoid writing the code for `INotifyPropertyChanged` every time in each ViewModel and Model i've created an abstract base class where everything is derived from. This class looks like:

```
public abstract class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly Dictionary<string, object> mapping;

  protected NotifyBase()
  {
    mapping = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  }

  protected void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    mapping[propertyName] = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
  }

  protected T Get<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    if(mapping.ContainsKey(propertyName))
      return (T)mapping[propertyName];
    return default(T);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemeberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null)
    {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I would have done intuitively, but that's not what msdn recommends though.